# Why is the basic example of the ArcGIS JavaScript API throwing an error?

Tags: javascript, arcgis

I'm trying to use the ArcGIS JavaScript API to build some interactive web maps. However, using the code found on [the official documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/display-a-map/) throws an error every time. I have a working API key, ommitted in the example below, of course.

Is there something I'm missing?

**Error:**

Exception has occurred.
Object

[image]

**Code:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>ArcGIS API for JavaScript Tutorials: Display a map</title>

    <style>
      html,
      body,
      #viewDiv {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.18/esri/themes/light/main.css">
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.18/"></script>

    <script>
      require(["esri/config","esri/Map", "esri/views/MapView"], function (esriConfig,Map, MapView) {

        esriConfig.apiKey = "YOUR_KEY_HERE";

        const map = new Map({
          basemap: "arcgis-topographic" // Basemap layer service
        });

        const view = new MapView({
          map: map,
          center: [-118.805, 34.027], // Longitude, latitude
          zoom: 13, // Zoom level
          container: "viewDiv" // Div element
        });

      });
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: I can't believe that I forgot to post that. See the updated post for the error.

Comment: Full error message? It appears to be truncated.

Comment: The message object contains little information (details == "undefined", name == "Aborted"). See edited post.

Comment: I ran this in CodePen with a developer's API key and it worked perfectly. Looks like something in your environment - network issue perhaps. I would contact ArcGIS for support.

Comment: Oki doke, many thanks for the quick replies :)